# cassandra nodetool compactionhistory interpertation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

When I run the command

```
nodetool compactionhistory
```

I get following output:

```
id                                       keyspace_name      columnfamily_name            compacted_at              bytes_in       bytes_out      rows_merged

---
01fd6ca0-d5b5-11e4-bc1e-8f1a146ee438     system             sstable_activity             1427593412714             3183           795            {4:16}

12e296c0-d30e-11e4-bc1e-8f1a146ee438     system             sstable_activity             1427301812780             4130           1069           {1:2, 4:24}
```

What does the last column indicate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566558/what-does-rows-merged-mean-in-compactionhistory question has been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

Its a histogram showing the number of rows merged in the compaction. The key is number of merged rows so `{1:2, 4:24}` means there was a row that did not need to be merged twice, and four rows merged 24 times.

Things like `{4:16}` would imply that the compaction is merging four sstables and there were 16 partitions (rows) that were shared in all of them.  With `{1:2, 4:24}` its saying that there were a couple partitions that were unique to a single sstable.

Worded a little differently https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCompactionHistory.html if it helps